# Haskell STM alwaysSucceeds

Tags: haskell, ghc, stm

There is a function in haskell's stm library with the following type signature:

```
alwaysSucceeds :: STM a -> STM ()
```

From what I understand of STM in haskell, there are three ways that something can "go wrong" (using that term loosely) while an STM computation is executing:

1. The value of an TVar that has been read is changed by another thread.
2. An user-specified invariant is violated. This seems to usually be triggered by calling `retry` to make it start over. This effectively makes the thread block and then retry once a TVar in the read set changes.
3. An exception is thrown. Calling `throwSTM` causes this. This one differs from the first two because the transaction doesn't get restarted. Instead, the error is propagated and either crashes the program or is caught in the IO monad.

If these are accurate (and if they are not, please tell me), I can't understand what `alwaysSucceeds` could possibly do. The `always` function, which appears to be built on top of it, seems like it could be written without `alwaysSucceeds` as:

```
--This is probably wrong
always :: STM Bool -> STM ()
always stmBool = stmBool >>= check
```

The documentation for `alwaysSucceeds` says:

> alwaysSucceeds adds a new invariant that must be true when passed to
>   alwaysSucceeds, at the end of the current transaction, and at the end
>   of every subsequent transaction. If it fails at any of those points
>   then the transaction violating it is aborted and the exception raised
>   by the invariant is propagated.

But since the argument is of type `STM a` (polymorphic in `a`), it can't use the value that the transaction returns for any part of the decision making. So, it seems like it would be looking for the different types of failures that I listed earlier. But what's the point of that? The STM monad already handles the failures. How would wrapping it in this function affect it? And why does the variable of type `a` get dropped, resulting in `STM ()`?

Comment: Since your comment there reminded me: there's a [current GHC proposal to deprecate this feature](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/77).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The special effect of `alwaysSucceeds` is not how it checks for failure at the spot it's run (running the "invariant" action alone should do the same thing), but how it *reruns* the invariant check at the end of transactions.

Basically, this function *creates* a user-specified invariant as in (2) above, that has to hold not just right now, but also at the end of later transactions.

Note that a "transaction" doesn't refer to every single subaction in the `STM` monad, but to a combined action that is passed to `atomically`.

I guess the `a` is dropped just for convenience so you don't have to convert an action to `STM ()` (e.g. with `void`) before passing it to `alwaysSucceeds`. The return value will be useless anyhow for the later repeated checks.

Comment: Got it. The real world haskell tutorial chapter 28 gives a fairly good example of this. So it seems like, if I understand correctly, `alwaysSucceeds` and `always` should both be called on something that has a possibility of calling `throwSTM`. It also seems like using a lot of these would significantly impact performance since they are rerun after every transaction.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin After some further testing, I don't think it has to be `throwSTM`, it seems like it can be `retry` based (including `check`), although if your invariant then fails, your transaction will retry indefinitely unless you have something in another thread that causes it to eventually succeed.

Comment: @AndrewThaddeusMartin An instructive test is: `do t <- newTVarIO 0; atomically . alwaysSucceeds $ readTVar t >>= check . (>= 0); forkIO $ forever (do threadDelay 10000000; atomically $ modifyTVar t (max 1)); replicateM_ 3 . atomically . modifyTVar t $ subtract 1`

Comment: I ran the test. Clever of you, it finally succeeds after 30 seconds, which makes sense. Although I feel like this way of using always seems a little odd and makes reasoning more difficult. Also, you could write functions like `f = alwaysSucceeds . alwaysSucceeds . alwaysSucceeds` which seems kind of bizarre. It feels like the result being in the IO monad instead would make more sense for `alwaysSucceeds`.